# fatal : Unable to find remote helper for 'gitL'

Tags: git

I am using git version 1.9.4-msysgit-0 and when I do git pull I get this error. I am excuting
git pull -s recursive upstream master.

I have tried looking around but I did not find what could be the reason. I am executing this command from the windows cmd. I tried to execute this from Git Bash but I see the same error.

Comment: Do you have a helper config listed anywhere? Check the output of `git config -l`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your git installation is corrupted, have you tried to download again or even a previous version of git?